# How do I prove that $f(A \times B)$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> $(\text a)$ Let $\Delta = \left \{(t_0,t_1,t_2)\ :\ t_0 + t_1 + t_2 = 1, t_i \geq 0\ \text {for}\ i=0,1,2 \right \}.$ Prove that the function $f : [0,1] \times [0,1] \longrightarrow \Delta$ defined by $$
> f(x_1,x_2) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             (x_1,x_2 - x_1,1 - x_2) & \quad \text {if}\ \ x_1 \leq x_2 \\
>             (x_2, x_1 - x_2,1 - x_1)  & \quad \text {if}\ \ x_2 \leq x_1
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1] \times [0,1].$
>
> $(\text b)$ Prove that $f(A \times B)$ is closed if $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $[0,1].$

I have proved part $(\text a)$ of the above question. How do I prove part $(\text b)$? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \times B$  is a closed subset of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and hence it is compact. Continuous image of a compact set is compact . Hence $f(A \times B)$ is compact, hence also closed.

Comment: sir compact subsets of a Hausdorff space is closed. Am I right?

Comment: @mathmaniac. Yes, that is exactly what I used.

Comment: $\Delta$ being a subspace of a Hausdorff space $\Bbb R^3$ it is Hausdorff too. This is the fact you have used here I suppose. Am I correct?

Comment: @mathmaniac. Right, it is understood that $\Delta$ is given the usual metric from $\mathbb R^{3}$ so  it is a nice metric space. Hence it is Hausdorff.